NiMh charging IC CN3085 timer issue
I'm using CN3085 IC to charge NiMh battery. I have issue with the charge maintenance timer.
According to the datasheet this timer is initiated once constant current charge mode is stopped.
The charge current in maintenance mode is 60% of the constant charge current. An internal timer is started once the CN3085 is in the maintenance charge mode, this puts a time limit on the maintenance charge mode, the time limit is programmed by a resistor and a
capacitor at the RC pin.
In maintenance charge mode, the time limit is determined by the following equation:
T=2654× R5× C1+4980× C1× 103
I'm using values according to the datahseet specifications: R5=3.6 Mohm C1=10 uf. However, the timer is not accurate, sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't turn on or off.Could someone  advise me on this issue ? Please find enclosed my schematic. Thank you.
